# Not able to boot to live USB from GRUB menu and there is also no recovery option

Tags: grub, live-usb, pop-os

[image]

I made a clean install of PopOS on my Lenovo Z580 using a live usb.
The live usb was flashed using Balena etcher from Xubuntu that was installed previously on the same machine.
Since then, I do not see any option to boot to live USB which still has the same PopOS iso 
When I press F2/F12 during boot, it just displays a single option to choose PopOS and not even an option for recovery.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the option to boot to usb is usually done from UEFI/bios, although it may be possible from GRUB as well in some situations. The ability to enter eufi/bios settings occurs before grub appears.

Are you using the right key to enter the uefi/bios settings? Some computers use other keys. Maybe include your computer make/model to get more feedback.

In the bios settings, there are options to enable/disable booting from usb. Check in your eufi/bios settings to see if this is enabled.